# Do equipment and weapons have tiers?

Tags: unturned

Do equipment and weapons (guns, melee, explosives) have tiers?

For example, is there a difference between the Berette (that's how it's spelled in game) and the Colt? Since in-game there's nothing to show whether or not one is better or not, I'm under the assumption they're the same? Are weapons more or less the same, or are there discernible benefits between different ones?

Same goes for cosmetic equipment, such as armor and clothing.  IS there any benefits to switching to different equipment?  Is armor going to protect me? Does it matter if I choose suits over construction vests?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are "tiers", the rarity of the weapon is what tells if it is stronger or not.

To more info about all firearms i recommend to see the link

http://unturned-bunker.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Firearms

Using the example you told about the Berette and the Colt, on the Berette wiki (http://unturned-bunker.wikia.com/wiki/Berette) one of its advantages is:
 - The Berette is able to inflict more damage than its more common counterpart; the Colt.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the berette deals more damage than the colt, but the Berette uses Label Ammunition and it's pretty rare, the Colt uses Swift Ammunition which is very common.

Answer (score 0):

Each gun deals a different amount of damage.  You can see all the different guns and the amount of damage they each do here:

https://unturned.gameinfo.io/set/guns

The [Colt](https://unturned.gameinfo.io/items/97-colt) does only 25 damage to players, whereas the [Avenger](https://unturned.gameinfo.io/items/1021-avenger) (the new Beretta) does 32.

---

The [melee weapons](https://unturned.gameinfo.io/set/melee) also deal different amounts of damage depending on the item.